# Make a Search box like angel.co/jobs

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter/PHP for my website.
How should i implement a search box like this?

[image: Search box]

Comment: You should now better. 
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Look at this link this may help for you...http://alxlit.name/bootstrap-chosen/